# Least number of moves to find $1$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Given an unknown permutation of $n$ integers (from $1$ to $n$), what is the minimum number of moves we need to guarantee that we can always find the $1$ in the sequence, given at each move we can ask about index ${i}$ and index ${j}$
and we get $ a_{i}$ mod $a_{j}$ in response.

Edit : The main problem is to find the complete sequence, and the optimal strategy I came up with was to find the $1$ in the sequence and then the answer will be minimum number of moves to find $1$, and then $n-1$ more moves. Is this the optimal strategy or there is a better way to approach this?

Example :
Let the hidden sequence is $5 \ 4 \ 1 \  3 \ 2$

If I ask about index $1$ and $2$ , I will get $1$.

If I ask about index $4$ and $3$ , I will get $0$.

If I ask about index $1$ and $3$ , I will get $0$.

If I ask about index $2$ and $3$ , I will get $0$.

If I ask about index $5$ and $3$ , I will get $0$.

Now I am sure index $3$ is $1$ and I can reproduce the sequence.

Comment: Please at least try to write your thought.

Comment: @Sumanta edited to add a little more background.

Comment: If $a_j$ happens to be $1$, do you get the answer $0$ back, regardless of what $a_i$ is? And in general, is the answer you get back always an integer in the range $[0,a_j)$?

Comment: @Arthur, Yes and $ i<j$ doesn't hold, but $ 1 < i,j <= n $ does.

Comment: If $n=1$, the task is completely trivial: you don't need any moves at all, while if $n=2$ it's clear that one move takes care of everything. I would start with $n=3$ and see what's the worst that can happen there, then try $n=4$, to test what the optimal strategy looks like in those cases. With luck a pattern will emerge that begins to clarify things

Comment: I would also suggest taking a "devil's advocate" approach to the analysis: Put yourself in the place of the person who gives the answer $a_i$ mod $a_j$ to input $i,j$, and allow yourself to give any answer that is consistent with all previous answers -- i.e., each answer reduces the pool of permutations, so try to give answers that keep the pool as large as possible for as long as possible.

Comment: Worst case is n-1 for n odd or even